# In Google Sheets, Is there a way to use hyperlinks in a data validated range?

Tags: validation, hyperlink, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, a cell using a data validated range consisting of hyperlinks will only display the link text and is not an actual link.

Example, I have a google spreadsheet consisting of 2 sheets.  Sheet 1 has a cell with data validation getting it's values from a range on sheet 2, like so `Sheet2!B2:B50`

Sheet 2 cell B2 contains a hyperlink like this:

`=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com", "LINK TEXT")`

When you select that item back in Sheet 1 in the validated cell, the cell only displays `LINK TEXT` and is not a hyperlink.

Is there a way to use hyperlinks in a data validated range?

Comment: Which sheet is validated, and as what?

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Apps, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I think, there's still no direct way to do this since you'd asked the question. But it's possible in two ways:

1. make `OnEdit` script and replace selected text with
   corresponding link
2. make 2 separate columns and emulate choise.

I want to suggest the second way as it's easier to implement.

The result will look like this:

[image]

Here's the [link to my test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z07ux0pp7w9lW-0riH6yhxjwX6H9Onisn7HZ8Id9lec/edit?usp=sharing).

---

**Step 1. Prepare data**

So Sheet2 contains data, it should look like this:

[image]

Separate:

- links in column B
- and their labels in column A.

**Step 2. Make Data Validation**

Go to Sheet1. And in required range make the new rule for Data Validation. In our sample it's column A. So select range > Go to Data > Validation... > select range `Sheet2!A2:A100` from your data sheet.

Note that in Google Sheets you may use bigger range for validation, sheets would ignore blanks.

Also there's a good reason to make the result of selection invisible. To make it, select custom number format and use this text:

```
;;;
```

**Step 2. Make Hyperlinks with formula**

In Sheet1, cell B2 paste the formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>"",HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),A2:A),""))
```

It will expand automatically.

That's all!